# AutoMapper > Using Queryable Extensions and some mapping fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, iqueryable

Is there any way to map these `EntityFramework` entities with AutoMapper?

I'm getting an error when trying to map a `DateTime` object (from my DBContext entity) to a `TimeSpan` property on my DTO.

This is the exception

```
----------- Exception #0 -----------
Type: System.NotSupportedException
Message: The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
Source: EntityFramework
```

It used to work when mapping the Entity after `ToList()` call, but now using AutoMapper's `ProjectTo<>` IQueryable extension it is obviously trying to convert the expression to an expression that SQL can understand.

My question - is it possible to configure mapping on certain objects to take place after the query has been executed on the server?  (e.g. after the `ToList()` call)

CloseTime property on the DB entity is a `DateTime` object but we are mapping to a `TimeSpan` object

For Now - I'm just ignoring the properties like so

```
cfg.CreateMap<CustomerShipTo, ShipToBase>()
    .ForMember(desc => desc.OpenTime, src => src.Ignore())
    //.ForMember(desc => desc.OpenTime, src => src.CloseTime.TimeOfDay)
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Could you share the models, your query where you are using `ProjectTo` and the error message you are receiving now. That would really help others to understand your issue.

Comment: Please be aware of a possible X/Y situation here: `My question - is it possible to configure mapping on certain objects to take place after the query has been executed on the server? (e.g. after the ToList() call)` Real problem is: "I'm getting an error when trying to map a DateTime object (from my DBContext entity) to a TimeSpan property on my DTO."

Comment: Exception details added ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.ProjectTo()` needs to be able to ultimately map down to SQL so there are limitations to what the mappings can do as compared to using `.Map()`. A work-around for issues like this is to map a "raw" data value then use a translation property in the DTO. In your case since this is a data type conversion you could call the raw value "OpenDateTime", normally if I want to use the same name I will use a prefix of "Raw" to reflect the raw DB value. (I.e. RawOpenTime)

```
[Serializable]
public class ShipToBase
{
    // ...
    public DateTime OpenDateTime { get; set; }
    public Timespan OpenTime
    {
        get { OpenDateTime.TimeOfDay; }
        set { OpenDateTime = DateTime.MinValue().Add(value); } // Setter if needed.
    }
}
```

Then in the mappings:

```
cfg.CreateMap<CustomerShipTo, ShipToBase>()
    .ForMember(desc => desc.OpenDateTime, src => src.OpenTime)
    .ForMember(desc => desc.OpenTime, src => src.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap();
```